# How to implement display trait for a struct with lifetime in rust?

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

I have a struct with string (&str) field in it,

```
struct Test<>{
    name: &str,
    city: &str,
}
```

while compiling this struct it returned a lifetime error and according to compiler suggestion added lifetime to it `<'a>` which worked.

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test<'a>{
    name: &'a str,
    city: &'a str,
}

impl fmt::Display for Test {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "name:{} city:{}", self.name,self.city)
    }
}


fn main(){
    let a = Test{name:"John",city:"London"};
    println!("{}",a);
}
```

I then tried to implement a display trait on this struct but its giving this error.

```
  | impl fmt::Display for Test {
  |                       ^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`
```

How to implement display trait for a struct with lifetime in rust?

Comment: And if you follow the compiler suggestion? Add the anonymous lifetime: `impl fmt::Display for Test<'_>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: use

```rust
impl<'a> fmt::Display for Test<'a>
```